# How can I create interactive caption for a video?

Tags: javascript, html5-video, interactive

I am looking into having a video and then have a caption underneath where the user can click and get a definition of a word, but I just can't figure out how to do it. I am looking into do it in javascript using the html5 video could anyone point me in the right direction or maybe there's a project somewhere about this?

Comment: You should take a screenshot of your rep :D

Answer (score 0):

This project seems to be good candidate for showing captions: http://bubbles.childnodes.com